# Shopify Webhooks for Collections do not work

Tags: shopify

I have created new Shopify Webhooks for topics `collections/create`, `collections/update` and `collections/delete` (as listed in the [Shopify API docs](http://api.shopify.com/webhook.html)).

The create Webhook gets empty body and no collection ID in headers.

```
{
    "x-shopify-topic": "collections/create",
    "x-shopify-shop-domain": "myshop.myshopify.com",
    "x-shopify-hmac-sha256": "MiTUUuy****************xZXScg=",
    "x-real-ip": "204.93.213.120",
    "x-forwarded-for": "204.93.213.120",
    "user-agent": "Ruby",
    "host": "postcatcher.in",
    "content-type": "application/xml",
    "content-length": "474",
    "connection": "close",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "x-heroku-queue-wait-time": "0",
    "x-heroku-queue-depth": "0",
    "x-heroku-dynos-in-use": "1",
    "x-request-start": "1343050015180" 
}
```

The other two Webhooks (update and delete) do not get called at all. Is this a bug in Shopify?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by listing the shop's webhooks using the API to make sure all three webhooks are there. There may have been a problem when creating the webhooks.

If they are in fact there, then I would contact the Shopify apps team directly: apps@shopify.com

Comment: I can see all three webhooks using the API. Other webhooks (for orders and products) work without any issues. Thanks anyway, I'll try to contact the Shopify team.